# Borrowing a Fostex FR-2LE

Tags: fostex, sound-devices

Hey all,

So my friend is letting me borrow his FR-2LE for a shoot this week since my H4n is being repaired. I usually use my SD MixPre with my Zoom.

I'll be getting it the day of the shoot so I really won't have time to test it out. Will I need to use the MixPre with the FR-2LE other than for a sine tone, or are the preamps of the Fostex good enough on their own? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Mix Pre preamps are much better than the preamps in the FR-2LE so I would use the line out from the Mix Pre into the Line input of the FR-2LE and work as normal.

Answer (score 2):

The preamps in the Fostex are pretty good but I'd definitely use your MixPre as they are better. Also you will have a much easier time adjusting levels on the MixPre.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Mark and Mike on this. Two major gotchas to be aware of, in addition:

1. The headphone amp is NOY-ZAY. Far noisier than the actual recorded signal. Don't let that throw you.
2. The CF cards need to be uniquely formatted for either stereo or mono. Super weird but there ya go.

Comment: I suppose I'll use my MixPre then. I don't want a "noy-zay" headphone amp haha.